# Getting married in Germany with a Schengen visa expiring soon

Tags: visa, marriage, schengen

Is it possible for a Schengen visa holder expiring soon to get married to a German citizen in Germany without having to leave and reentering the country?
In any case, what will be the problems one will face if his visa expired in this situtation?

Comment: Three different questions here -- can you get married, how does the marriage affect your immigration status, and what happens if you overstay?

Comment: Yes, exactly, well summarized

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Foreigners who want to marry in Germany have to show documents from their homeland that they *can* legally marry, e.g. that there are no previous marriages or that they are properly divorced. Getting those documents on short notice could be difficult.
- Marriages for the sole purpose of gaining immigration status (Scheinehe) may be dissolved by the courts, using them to gain immigration permits may be punishable for *both* partners. On the other hand, genuine marriages are protected by the constitution and laws, the two partners have a right to live together as a family. In a case like yours, questions would be raised. Can you answer them?
- People who are getting married have to prove their identity to the registrar. They have to show their papers.

Summarized, I don't think your idea is practical. In the few cases I know personally, the non-EU partner had always applied for a temporary residency permit first. This gave the time for the bureaucratic steps and gave the family time to apply for *tourist* visa for the celebrations.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
P.S. it's not me who gets married :D

Comment: There is a world between “being in love” and “Scheinehe”. Last I checked, marital life is what's required, not love.

Comment: @Gala, I wrote that "questions will be raised," to pin just that difference down.

Comment: I was thinking about the last paragraph, which I find unrealistic and patronising.

Comment: @Gala, edited. abdeaitali sounded a bit desperate, so I wondered if there were reasons why he **can't** go home.